# Tidy URL losing relative links

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been implementing tidy urls and querystrings into my site but can't get querystrings to resolve AND show the page correctly - all links become relative to the 'faux' directory

I'm using

```
RewriteRule ^services/([0-9]+)/?$ services.php?sv=$1
```

in .htaccess

```
so /services/2 becomes /services.php?sv=2
```

but the resulting page displays incorrectly.

I can only think that it's impossible to use relative links when using tidy urls and querystrings but I can find no mention of this anywhere.

Standard link: http://www.tomatedesign.com/sample-site/services.php?sv=2 as normal with querystring

and finally: http://www.tomatedesign.com/sample-site/services/2  tidy URL with a querystring

The RewriteRule is doing its job, services/1, services/2 and services/3 all get the correct content included on the page just everything else is broken.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but try adding " [QSA]" (without the quotes) at the end of the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I just had to include

```
<base href="/">
```

in the file to have the page resolve the links appropriately